# Question about KuCoin historical market data (OHLCV)

Tags: database, validation

I have been searching for days for a free source to obtain KuCoin historical market data (OHLCV) on an hourly frequency. Their API is quite limited as it doesn't include delisted coins. I am interested in undertaking an ML project with their data, given that they are an exchange with good liquidity and a large number of coins. However, finding data online has proven to be challenging. Does anyone have any recommendations or has anyone stored their historical data over the last few years? Thanks in advance!

I tried using their API and attempted to find information online regarding whether someone stored the data continuously. Quite soon, I realized that their API only offers currently listed coins, so it was a no-go. I came across a few data providers, but they charge a lot for the data, and usually, they don't offer specific exchange data. Data providers typically cover all exchanges and create their own products, selling them as such. I am specifically interested in data that comes directly from the exchange, not data that an intermediary provider creates. If anyone has had struggles in the past and found a solution, that would be much appreciated.